# Any way for a non-moderator to see site statistics?

Tags: discussion, questions, statistics

I am curious is there is a URI where a non-moderator can view site statistics.

Answer (score 4):

At 25,000 reputation, [users gain access to various analytic data](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), including selected data from Google Analytics. Users with access can visit [site analytics](https://serverfault.com/site-analytics) to see the data.

At 10,000 reputation, [users gain access to moderator tools](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), including some [limited statistics](https://serverfault.com/tools?tab=stats) about recent questions and answers.

Comment: ahhh....nice answer, but I meant for normal folks with under 25000 points.

Comment: @mdpc Oh, I totally forgot, there are a few stats available at 10K. Answer updated.